# Access : how do i cancel an action if the data entered in the fields on the main matches data from a table displayed in a subform?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a Main Form with 3 fields, where the rep would enter the Property, Room Type, and the requested Check-in Date - however on the same form i have a subform displaying Property, Room Type and Check-in Dates NOT AVAILABLE. If a rep enters data in those 3 fields and ALL 3 match what is in the NOT AVAILABLE subform - what code (either VBA or On Lost Focus etc) can i use to look up those values in the subform (so that if it matches what's in the subform it will not allow for submission) and also popup an ERROR message that the "Property, Room Type and Check-In Date you selected are not available" ?

(Main Form data entered will go into a table let's say RoomRequestTable and Not Available subform displays data from another table RoomNotAvailableTable)

Comment: So your users will enter information on the main form? To be validated against the information in the subform?

Comment: You can use Before Update event and some SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Below is some sample code utilizing the [BeforeUpdate event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822421%28v=office.15%29.aspx). I'm assuming you want to trigger this from any of the fields, so I wrote a sample function that returns false if all of the fields match. We access the subform by calling `Me.[SubFromName].Form`.

```
Private function validate() As Boolean
    Dim sbfrm As Form
    Set sbfrm = Me.SubFormName.Form
    If Me.FieldName = sbfrm.FieldName And Me.FieldName2 = sbfrm.FieldName2 And Me.FieldName3 = sbfrm.FieldName3 Then
        MsgBox "you can't do that", vbExclamation, "Sorry kid"
        'return false
        validate = false
    Else
        'return true
        validate = true
    End If
End Function

Private Sub ControlName1_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Cancel = Not validate
    If Cancel then
        Me.ControlName1.Undo
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ControlName2_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Cancel = Not validate
    If Cancel then
        Me.ControlName2.Undo
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ControlName3_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Cancel = Not validate
    If Cancel then
        Me.ControlName3.Undo
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for the info. i'm not sure what i may be doing wrong. but i've entered the code you've given me (with my subform name, field names) and it still let's the submission go thru. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you copy/paste the code, or did you use the event builder in design view. You have to do that to get Access to recognize that you've added an event. One of M$'s "features".

Comment: i started from scratch and did the event builder. now i'm getting the "Compile Error: Expected End Function" .

Comment: Private Function validate() As Boolean
    Dim sbfrm As Form
    Set sbfrm = Me.RoomNADatesSubForm.Form
    If Me.PropertyNum = sbfrm.Property And Me.Unit = sbfrm.UnitType And Me.ReqCIDate = sbfrm.NotAvailableDate Then
        MsgBox "you can't do that", vbExclamation, "Sorry kid"
        'return false
        validate = False
    Else
        'return true
        validate = True
    End If
End Sub

Comment: @user3585895 I accidentally used `End Sub` instead of `End Function`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Quite a complicated approach.

Comment: @ckuhn203  . i thought that was the case, but when i changed it to End Function that's when it allows it to be submitted. :( i hope we can figure it out. i will continue to change some things around. let me know any other suggestions. thank you for all your help so far :).

Comment: Don't forget that you have to swap out all of the field names and control names. Also, I built the function based on your requirement that "All 3 match what is not available". This is not functioning code. It is to display the concept to you.

Comment: Yes i did change all the field names and control names. And yes if all 3 match the not available subform then it should not allow for submission.Thank you again.

Comment: If anyone has any other recommendations i'm open to suggestions. @Remou do you have anything in mind?

Comment: @ckuhn203 i had this working. but i would click on the "Close" btn (instead of "Submit") it allowed the record to be inserted in the table. i tried adding the validate on the close btn. somewhere along the way, the code stopped working. now this code ONLY checks the first record in my subform table :( .  it's not doing the MoveNext/Loop function as it did before on it's own. Please Help!

Comment: @fionnuala what is your recommendation for my question?